# Topology (invariant under homeomorphism)

Tags: general-topology

Prove or refute, the condition of separation of a topological space is invariant under homeomorphism.
I have to find homeomorphism with $T_0,T_1,T_2,\ldots$ 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Suppose $X$ has the property.  Suppose $h: X \to Y$ is a homeo.  Prove that $Y$ has the property.

Comment: Is the property any axioms?

Comment: @Ck27 It could be the separation axioms or the property of being separable (having a countable dense subset). It doesn't matter in the sense that it's a true statement in either case. Since you have the context, you are the best one to judge which it is. How did you come across this question?

Comment: It's a question that a teacher gives me, I have to look if I can do it an homeomorphism between T0 to T0 (it preserves), the same with T1-T1, T2-T2,T3-T3 and T4-T4, but how can I do it that homeomorphism? Because I have open sets with the axioms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show how it works for $T_2$ and let you work out the details for the rest. To show $T_2$ is homeomorphism preserving, we suppose $X$ is a $T_2$ topological space and $Y$ is a topological space that is homeomorphic to $X$. We now wish to conclude that $Y$ is $T_2$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, there is a homeomorphism $h:X\to Y$. To prove that $Y$ is $T_2$, we need to show that it satisfies the definition. To this end, fix distinct points $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $Y$. Since $h$ is a homeomorphism, it is onto. Thus there are points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$ such that $h(x_1)=y_1$ and $h(x_2)=y_2$. Because $h$ is a function, we know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ must be distinct. Now using the fact that $X$ is $T_2$, we can find disjoint open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $x_1\in U$ and $x_2\in V$. Because homeomorphisms are open maps, the sets $h(U)$ and $h(V)$ are open in $Y$. Moreover $y_1=h(x_1)\in h(U)$ and $y_2=h(x_2)\in h(V)$. Therefore it remains to show that $h(U)$ and $h(V)$ are disjoint.

Suppose they are not disjoint. Then there exists $y\in Y$ such that $y\in h(U)\cap h(V)$. Thus there exists $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ satisfying $y=h(u)=h(v)$. Because $h$ is an injection, we deduce $u=v\in U\cap V$. This contradicts the fact that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Consequently $Y$ is $T_2$.

Comment: wha is f? When you say h(x1)∈ f(U)

Comment: @Ck27 Whoops! That should be $h(x_1)\in h(U)$ and likewise $h(x_2)\in h(V)$. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Oh ya, jaja thank you so much.

Comment: Hey... I have a question, T0, T1, T2, T3 and T4, all of this can be thought at the same logic, all are invariant under homeomorphism?

Comment: @Ck27 Yeah they are all invariant. Try proving that. It should be similar to the proof above for $T_2$.

Comment: But when I do T3 I fix a y and a closed A so, I know that there is a x in X such that f(x)=y but with the closed how can I do it?

Comment: @Ck27 You want to get a closed set in $X$ using the closed set in $Y$. The homeomorphism $f$ is exactly how you will travel back and forth between the spaces. So take $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(A)$. Since $f$ is invertible, these both make sense. Since $y\not\in A$ we know $f^{-1}(y)\not\in f^{-1}(A)$. Lastly, since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed.